# POST with Ext.Ajax.request?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, extjs

I am new to ExtJS and I am trying to implement a combo box and 'Save' button that will save the "boxStatus" for all of the records selected in my grid (there is a little checkbox column for selecting records, and a combo box for the status).  I have tried with the following ajax call:

```
saveBulkBoxComments : function(){
    var formObj = this.getPositionPanel().getForm();
    var fieldValues = formObj.getFieldValues();

        Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: SAVE_BULK_BOX_COMMENTS_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            positionDate: this.parentRecordData.data.positionDate,
            groupIds: this.parentRecordData.data.groupId,
            boxStatus: fieldValues.boxStatus,
            csrComment: fieldValues.csrComment
        },
        success : function(response) {
                //how do I update box status for all records selected?
                this.loadPositions();
        },
        scope: this
        });
}
```

Here is the Java:

```
return getReturnValue(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {     
            String groupIdList[] = groupIds.split(",");     
            String user = mercuryUserScreenNameGetter.getValue(request);
            Date date = Utils.parseDate(positionDate, DATE_FORMAT);
            Stream.of(groupIdList)
                .forEach(groupId -> 
                positionsDataMediator.addBoxAnnotation(date,user, groupId,   csrComment, boxStatus));           
            }
});
```

I am not really sure how to post all of the boxStatus for all of the records selected.  Would I have to write a method that iterates over all of the records when I hit Save?  That seems wrong...Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would you mind reproducing a simplified version of your Ext form using https://fiddle.sencha.com/ so that it's easier for others to review?

Comment: I am trying to do is update all of the cells in a single column in bulk. So I would select all of the group status at once and hit update, to post to the server.  I am just not sure how to post all of them with a single call.

Comment: Does `fieldValues.boxStatus` contain all of the values you need to send to the server?

Comment: No that is one param.  As you can see from the code below I need to send all of those, plus groupIds as an array of groupId values.  I would not be able to update all of the values for boxStatus if I don't have the groupIds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling, I got it working.  The trick was to iterate over each groupID, for all of the selected records...this way I was able to update the boxStatus for each of those records at once:

```
saveBulkBoxComments : function(){


         grid = this.getPositionPanel();
         var store = grid.getStore();


         formObj = this.getBoxCommentsFormPanel().getForm();
         var fieldValues = formObj.getFieldValues();

         var value='';


         selectedRecords = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();


         Ext.each(selectedRecords, function(item) {
             value +=item.get('groupId') +',';
             }            
         );

         Ext.Ajax.request({
             url: SAVE_BULK_BOX_COMMENTS_URL,
             method: 'POST',
             params: {
                 groupIds :value,
                 positionDate: this.parentRecordData.data.positionDate,
                 boxStatus: fieldValues.boxStatus,
                 csrComment: fieldValues.csrComment

             },

             success: function(result, action, response) {
                 var jsonData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);


                 var jsonRecords = jsonData.records;

                 Ext.getCmp('boxCommentsWindow').close();
                 this.loadPositions();

                },

                scope: this 
                });
             }


});
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! I apologize for not helping more. I rarely sign in to Stack Overflow and forgot to return.

Comment: You may consider using `jsonData` instead of `params` depending on how much data you want to send across, though. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Request.html#cfg-jsonData